# i am trying to setup my dvwa it shows a error message.."COULD NOT COONECT TO THE MYSQL SERVICE"

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, localhost

i am trying to setup my dvwa it shows a error message..

i also removed the password  from config file. but it doesn't work. it shows the same error.

**ERROR MESSAGE**
could not connect to the mysql service .
Your database user is root, if you are using MariaDB, this will not work, please read the README.md file.

**I have tried method**
1. removed the password in config file..still doesn't work..
2. it shows the error as root user name will not work in MariaDB .

Comment: So, are you using MariaDB?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MariaDB

Comment: What username is being used in the config file? And have you read the README.md file?

Comment: $_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'root';
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';   it shows a error message... i also changed my username into 'dvwa' and 'admin'. But it doesn't work.The readme files shows "connect to the database as the root user"..I am using windows 10 .what should i do.

Comment: Did you read the section under Database Setup on the [README.md](https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/DVWA/blob/master/README.md)?